# Meteor Autoform input fields only take up half a line instead of entire lines

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am create a user administration panel and my add user modal looks fine where each input takes up the entire line and the next input is on the next line. In my edit user modal the inputs only use up half a line. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Add User template:

```
<template name="addUser">
  {{#autoForm id="addUser" type="method" meteormethod="createUserwRole" collection="Users" resetOnSuccess="true" validation="keyup" }}
  <fieldset>
        {{> afQuickField name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="profile" id="profile" autocomplete="off"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="emails.$.address" id="emails" autocomplete="off"}}
        {{> afFormGroup name="roles" options=options type="select-checkbox" id="roles"}}
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUser">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Edit user template:

```
<template name="editUser">
    <div>
      {{#autoForm id="editUser" type="method-update" meteormethod="createUserwRole" collection="Users" resetOnSuccess="true" validation="keyup" }}
      <fieldset>
            {{> afQuickField name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off"}}
            {{> afQuickField name="profile" id="profile" autocomplete="off"}}
            {{> afQuickField name="emails.$.address" id="emails" autocomplete="off"}}
            {{> afFormGroup name="roles" options=options type="select-checkbox" id="roles"}}
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUser">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      {{/autoForm}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey, since you are using `AutoForm` and trying to build a admin panel, you could try my package https://atmospherejs.com/kaoskeya/admin
You could also check https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you got a div wrapping your edit form, but that is missing from your add form. If your divs have a default width that could explain it. 
I suggest making the html match if you want to replicate the layout.

Comment: I removed the div but no luck fixing the issue.

Comment: inspect the css using developer tools, ensure both templates are called inside similar containers, it seems like your edit form is nested inside a col-xs-6 or something similar if you are using bootstrap

Comment: It is not wrapped inside of a col-xs-6. The edit version is built within a table and I found that if I move it out of the table it works properly. It must be inheriting something from the table

Comment: I suspected as much, inherited styling can be a tricksy rabbit.